# How to stop sprite from moving?

Tags: easeljs

I'm playing around with easeljs library. I have manage to create a small sprite, that will move each time I press the right arrow from the keyboard. Right now I'm presenting the issue, that if I don't have any key press the sprite gives the impression that it moves, (Basically it's changing from image one to image 2)

I have the demo here in code pen: https://codepen.io/diegotc/pen/qKezQB

I think the problem is how I'm managing my run, with the images.

```
 spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
        framerate: 5,
        "images": ["https://preview.ibb.co/eLKC7T/man2_rt1.gif","https://preview.ibb.co/ccR3E8/man2_rt2.gif"],
        "frames": {"regX": 82, "height": 32, "count": 2, "regY": 0, "width": 32},
        "animations": {
            "run": [0,1,"run",1],
            "stop": [0,"stop",0]
        }
    });
```

Or should I be calling stop, intermediately after I call run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that are preventing the effect you want.

1. You can control SpriteSheets. Rather than having "Grant" and "Begin", just have one. You can tell that Sprite to gotoAndStop/gotoAndPlay to have it change states. That is the reason the spritesheet has multiple animations.
2. When you press the key down, the only action you want to happen every time is to move the sprite. You should only call `gotoAndPlay()` (or swap sprites like you are doing) **one time**, when you first start moving. Then when you stop moving (keyup), stop the sprite.
3. Only add the tick listener once. You already had the global one in init(), that is enough, it runs constantly.
4. Moving on "keydown" is not ideal, since keydown events fire once when you press, and then begin repeating after a short delay. It is better to trigger an animation loop on the press, instead of just moving on press.

Example:

```
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tickFn);
document.addEventListener('keydown' ,(event) =>{
    const keyName = event.key;

    let wasMoving = moving;
    if (keyName == 'ArrowRight') {
        moving = true;
    }

    if (moving != wasMoving) {
      grant.gotoAndPlay("run");
    }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  const keyName = event.key;
  if (keyName === 'ArrowRight') {
    moving = false;
    grant.gotoAndStop("stop");
  }
});

// Instead of ticking the stage, tick this function. Then update the stage yourself
function tickFn(event) {
  if (moving) {
    if(grant.x > stage.canvas.width){
      grant.x = 50;
    }
    grant.x += 10;
  }
  stage.update(event);
};
```

I updated your [codepen to do the above](https://codepen.io/lannymcnie/pen/KBPQPO), and also added a few other modifications:

- Fixed the regX on the spritesheet. It was set to 82, which pushes your sprite out the the right by almost 3x. I set it to 50% of the width, so its in the center. I then moved it to 50px
- I added a `preventDefault` on the key events to prevent the page from scrolling
- I added left-moving, by setting the `scaleX=-1`, and then setting a "direction" for the movement to multiply.
- I changed the Spritesheet animation format for you "run" ([to complex](https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/SpriteSheet.html)) so that the first frame is 1, and not 0. This makes your sprite start walking immediately, rather than playing the stop frame first.

I hope this answers your question, and also sheds some light on your next steps.
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @Lanny, can it be possible if you can share the codepen you modify?

Comment: Added an option to the codepen make him moonwalk, because why not?